# Vector Space, Dimension, Subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Suppose that *V* is a vector space and dim(*V*) = 4. *W* is a subspace of *V*. Prove directly that *W* must have finite dimension.

My Answer:
Since *W* is a subspace of *V*, dim(*W*) must be less or equal to dim(*V*). Since dim(*V*) = 4, dim(*W*) should, at most, be 4, which is a finite number. Therefore, *W* has a finite dimension.

Just wondering if this is correct?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think this is what the question asks you to do. The word "directly" seems to imply that you should not apply the general theorem but rather find a finite generating set (but otherwise, of course your proof is correct).

Comment: Yes, the argument is correct. Depending on what you have done in class you may be expected to say something about why the dimension of subspaces is smaller than the dimension of the enclosing space.

Comment: I guess you should prove that ($W$ subspace of $V$)$\implies$ ($\dim w\leq \dim V$).

Comment: The statement is correct, though I suspect that the "directly" in the question is specifically meant to prevent you from using that argument.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks a lot for your comments. I will try to prove that W, subspace of V, has at most the dimension of V, and post it under this post then. Thanks a lot once again

Answer (score 0):

just wondering what do you think about this proof

Let S: {($x,y,z,t$)|$x=t: x,y,z,t ∈ W$}

Given, dim(*W*) = 4

Addition:
Let u = ($x_1$,$y_1$,$z_1$,$t_1$) and v= ($x_2$,$y_2$,$z_2$,$t_2$), *u* and *v* ∈ W

*u+v* = ($x_1+x_2$, $y_1+y_2$, $z_1+z_2$, $t_1+t_2$)

since $u+v$ ∈ *W*, this set is closed under addition.

Multiplication: Let *k* be any scalar ∈ ℝ

Consider *ku* = (k$x_1+kx_2$, $ky_1+ky_2$, $kz_1+kz_2$, $kt_1+kt_2$)
since *ku* ∈ *V*, this set is closed under multiplication.

Nonemptiness: Since 0 ∈ *u*, and 0 ∈ *v*, 0 also ∈ S.
Hence the set is nonempty.

Since $x=t, u$=($x_1$,$y_1$,$z_1$,$x_1$), hence dim($S$) = 3

Because the maximum quantity of parameter in S is 4, dim(*W*) is at most 4, and could be less should similar event to example above occurs.

Therefore dim(*W*)is a finite number.

*sorry if the proof looks bad

Kindly let me know your suggestions

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Every set of $5$ elements of $W$ must be linearly dependent because this holds for $V$.

This proves that $\dim W \le 4$.